# GCC 4.9 std::string from const char*

Tags: c++11, gcc, stdstring

I'm trying to build a std::string from a buffer but I have a strange problem.
Seems that this two piece of code are different:

```
std::string myfun()
{
    ....
    std::string rv{};
    if (....)
    {
        char ibuff[256];
        memcpy(ibuff, m_buffer + off - 28, len);
        ibuff[len] = 0;
        rv.assign(ibuff);
    }
    ...
    return rv;
}
```

and

```
std::string myfun()
{
    ....
    std::string rv{};
    if (....)
    {
        rv.assign(m_buffer + off - 28, len);
    }
    ...
    return rv;
}
```

I'm can see an extra (unprintable) character in second case.

Comment: What is `m_buffer`? What is `off`? What is `len`? What are their values and content? How do you know there's an "extra" character in the string? Please to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: @dude: I'm tryng to prepare a simple example

Comment: @nos: yes for sure in not null terminated. But from what I know this is not a problem when you copy a buffer inside std::string

Comment: If there are `'\0'` characters in `m_buffer`, then the first example truncates at the first such character, while the second makes it, and subsequent characters, part of the string. In other words, in the first example it's possible that `rv.length() < len`, while in the second it's guaranteed that `rv.length() == len`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in other part of the code as usual!
Infact this code works as expected.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char buff[512];
    std::string rv{};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 512; i++)
        buff[i] = i & 0xef;


    buff[179] = 'X';
    buff[180] = 'Y';
    buff[181] = 'Z';
    buff[182] = '.';

    uint16_t off = 179;
    uint16_t len = 4;

    rv.assign(buff + off, len);
    std::cout << "[[[" << rv << "]]]\n";
}
```